# How can i a string use as a objectname in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

How can i use a string as a object name?

```
var a = "hello",
    b = {
      hello : "word"
    };


alert(b.a);
```

This give my a in empty box.
I want to still use the variable a.

Comment: `b[a]`. Read some tutorial, please.

Comment: maybe you can still use it also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i a string use as a objectname in javascript?

This is how you do it.

```
window["obj"] = { hello:"word"};
```